# Adding custom link buttons to ASP GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following GridView in which I have a select button in the first column that selects the row.

I want to put another similar (custom/user defined) button in a new column right next to select button called `"Compute"`. How can I do that?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSavingsTracker" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridViewSavingsTracker_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="creditorName" HeaderText="Creditor Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Principal Amount" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="interestRate" HeaderText="Interest Rate" />   
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Text_on_the_Button" CommandName="Command1" ButtonType="Link" />
```

`Command_Name` = Gets or Sets a string that represents the action to perform when a button in a *ButtonField* object is clicked.

And on server side:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="Command1")
    {
        // What you want to do when the button is clicked.
    }
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield(v=vs.110).aspx